# Convert a React.element to a JSX string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a component which,

1. Takes children and
2. Renders the children in the DOM and also,
3. Shows the children DOM in a `pre` for documentation sake

One solution is to pass the JSX as a separate `prop` as well. This makes it repetitive since I am already able to access it through `this.props.children`. Ideally, I just need to somehow convert the `children` prop as a `string` so that I can render it in a `pre` to show that *"this code produces this result"*.

This is what I have so far

```
class DocumentationSection extends React.Component{
        render(){
           return <div className="section"> 
                    <h1 className="section__title">{heading || ""}</h1> 
                    <div className="section__body"> {this.props.children}</div>
                    <pre className="section__src">
                        //Change this to produce a JSX string from the elements
                        {this.props.children}
                    </pre>
                </div>;
         }  
}
```

How can I get the a jsx string in the format `'<Div className='myDiv'>...</Div>` when I render DocumentationSection as

```
<DocumentationSection heading='Heading 1'>
    <Div className='myDiv'>...</Div>
</DocumentationSection>
```

Thanks.

**Edit**:

I tried toString, it dint work, gave [object Object]

Comment: I think you can pick a winner now.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want the HTML representation of a React element you can use `#renderToString` or `#renderToStaticMarkup`.

```
import ReactDomServer from 'react-dom/server';

ReactDomServer.renderToString(<div>p</div>);
ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<div>p</div>);
```

will produce

```
<div data-reactid=".1" data-react-checksum="-1666119235">p</div>
```

and

```
<div>p</div>
```

respectively. You will however not be able to render the parent as a string from within itself. If you need the parent too then from where you render the parent pass a `renderToString` version of it as props to itself.

Comment: Hmm, good one. I am able to get a HTML representation. But can I get JSX too? The exact props.children element as a string.

Comment: Not in a built-in way, no, there are several projects on github that will take JSX and output it to a string however.

Comment: `React.renderToString` is deprecated since React 0.14.0, use `ReactDomServer.renderToString` instead.

Comment: `ReactDOMServer` can be imported like this: `import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';`

Answer (score 31):

`React.renderToString` is depreciated as of `React v0.14.0`, it's recommended to use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` instead.

e.g

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
...
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(YourJSXElement())
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [react-element-to-jsx-string](https://github.com/algolia/react-element-to-jsx-string):

```
import React from 'react';
import reactElementToJSXString from 'react-element-to-jsx-string';

console.log(reactElementToJSXString(<div a="1" b="2">Hello, world!</div>));
// <div
//   a="1"
//   b="2"
// >
//   Hello, world!
// </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [pretty-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-format) package, which is part of Jest, and used by Jest to show the diffs in JSX assertions.

```
import React from "react";
import prettyFormat from "pretty-format";
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
const { ReactTestComponent } = prettyFormat.plugins;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
   </div>
  );
}

console.log(
    prettyFormat(renderer.create(<App />), {
        plugins: [ReactTestComponent],
        printFunctionName: true,
    })
);
```

This will output something like:

```
<div
  className="App"
>
  <h1>
    Hello CodeSandbox
  </h1>
  <h2>
    Start editing to see some magic happen!
  </h2>
</div>
```

You can try it by yourself in this CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xvxlw370xp

Comment: Any idea how to change the formatting of pretty-format such that `<h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1> shows up on one line? I'm using it now but having trouble formatting when new lines appear