# How to render (print) JSX as String?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Here JSX is scode sample:

```
export default class Element extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="alert alert-success">
          {this.props.langs.map((lang, i) => <span key={i} className="label label-default">{lang}</span>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How to get string like this?

```
<div><div className="alert alert-success">{this.props.langs.map((lang, i) => <span key={i} className="label label-default">{lang}</span>)}</div></div>
```

**UPD:** I got React components which I render on the server. I want to get them as a strings to transform them for another templating library on client side.

Comment: What is the context? Why do you need this and using what methods?

Comment: Not clear. There might be different approaches depending on what you actually want to achieve and why.

Comment: Might not be possible. The JS code inside the `<div>` is evaluated before the `<div>` is even constructed.

Comment: Is this what you are asking for? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a React.element to a JSX string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114679/convert-a-react-element-to-a-jsx-string)

Answer (score 55):

just call `renderToStaticMarkup()` and you should get the static html markup language generated by React.

somewhat like this:

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import Element from './path/to/element/class';

const element = <Element />;

ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)
```

here are some more docs about this:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup

Comment: Note: this gives you the HTML that will get put on the page as a string, not the jsx, but luckily that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but it adds a lot of unexpected things to it.  This is what I get.

Comment: It looks like its adding other tags.

Comment: This is perfect. #renderToStaticMarkup() doesn't add extra attributes, but #renderToString() apparently does.