# How to convert react component to html string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have found similar to my issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3386).

But I have a little bit different scenario. I have string of html rather than just string. So, I wanted to do:

Let's suppose MyComponent is just returning h3 element for now:

```
const MyComponent = ({children}) => (<h3>{children}</h3>)

var parts = "<h1>I</h1><p>am a cow;</p>cows say moo. MOOOOO."
    .split(/(\bmoo+\b)/gi);
for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
  parts[i] = <MyComponent key={i}>{parts[i]}</MyComponent>;
}
// But I need html to be rendered
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: parts }} />
```

This will be rendered in the  browser like this:

```
I
am a cow;
cows say ,[object Object],. ,[object Object],.
```

What I can think here to resolve the issue is converting component with string of html first.

```
parts[i] = convertToStringOfHtml(<MyComponent key={i}>{parts[i]}</MyComponent>);
```

But I don't have idea how to convert component to string of html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a React.element to a JSX string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114679/convert-a-react-element-to-a-jsx-string)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do with react-dom

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
//
//
parts[i] = renderToString(<MyComponent key={i}>{parts[i]}</MyComponent>)
```

view more here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: Thanks. renderToString is what I was looking for. But I need to use `parts[i] = renderToString(<MyComponent key={i}>{parts[i]}</MyComponent>);` not in __html.

Comment: Appreciated your answer. But you may update the answer.

Comment: Please help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916251/how-to-replace-multiple-instance-of-string-at-once

Answer (score 4):

You can also do something like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";


const Hello = () => <div>hello</div>;

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Hello />);

console.log(html.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs here: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code

---

Importing `react-dom/server` **on the client** unnecessarily increases your bundle size and should be avoided. If you need to render some component to HTML in the browser, use `createRoot` and read HTML from the DOM:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

const div = document.createElement('div');
const root = createRoot(div);
flushSync(() => {
  root.render(<MyIcon />);
});
console.log(div.innerHTML); // For example, "<svg>...</svg>"
```

The `flushSync` call is necessary so that the DOM is updated before reading its `innerHTML` property.