# How to replace multiple instance of string at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently repeating the task like below:

```
var parts = "<h1>I</h1><p>am a cow;</p>cows say moo. MOOOOO."
    .split(/(\bmoo+\b)/gi);
for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
  parts[i] = renderToString(<MyComponent key={i}>{parts[i]}</MyComponent>);
}

var anotherParts = parts.split(/(\bcow+\b)/gi);
for (var i = 1; i < anotherParts.length; i += 2) {
   anotherParts[i] = renderToString(<MyOtherComponent key={i}>
        {anotherParts[i]}
     </MyOtherComponent>)
}

return anotherParts
```

Is this possible to do the above task at once? I'm looking for most feasible way to do that because I wanted to replace more and more multiple strings.

Comment: `replace()` method with global option

Comment: Is var anotherParts= parts.split() giving an error?

Comment: It's returning the string.. updated the question for that.

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem and what you're trying to achieve. Please provide desirable output for this input. Should cow and moo be counted separately? Then this cannot be done at once. `i += 2` - what is that for?